# How to find largest subarray of sum k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window, sub-array

Let's say you have given an array of size N, which can have a positive and a negative number.
we need to return the length of the largest subarray of sum equal to k. I tried to use the sliding window algorithm but soon I found out it won't work here since the array element can have a positive and negative integer.

For E.g:

arr=[-20,-38,-4,-7,10,4] and k = 3 It's obvious, there are two possible subarray ([-4,-7,10,4] and [-7,10]) whose sum will equal to given k. So the output will be 4(Length of largest subarray)

The brute force approach will take O(n^2) is there any better way to do the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make a hashtable.

Walk through array, calculating cumulative sum (from 0th item upto i-th one), and put result in hash table with current sum as key and for value -insert index into pair of the first ans last occurence like this: `{13:[2,19]}` sum 13 is met first at index 2 and rightmost position for this sum is 19.

Then scan array again. For index `i` with sum `S` look hashtable for key `S + k` and choose the farthest index. For example, having index 5, sum 6, k=7 we can find the farthest index 19 in example above.